# How can I resize an image grid dynamically as the browser width/height changes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I'm trying to design a page which contains a list of images and on re-size of the browser/window the images should get adjusted in such a way that the images should be in only three rows. For example initially I have 10 images in a row and as a whole I have total  30 images in three rows. When I re-size the window the images should get adjusted (as the window gets smaller, the grid goes to 7 images in a row and then to 5 images in a row). And at any point of time I should have only 3 rows.

I have added the below link which is serving same kind of purpose.

e.g.  https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/about/?icm=tabz

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Show some code, what are you tried to do?

Comment: You can use css media queries to hide (set display: none) to images you don't need on specific width.

Comment: @jcubic Thanks for the quick reply, dynamically when re-sizing the window how can we know which images to hide?

Comment: If I would do something like this I would resize and test which images to hide and use `nth-child` pseudo selector to select the right images.

Comment: Your images should have a class say " ImagesContainer ". Add a media Query that sets the property of that class display:None

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That Mozilla page uses Animated Responsive Image Grid, a jquery plugin:

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/08/02/animated-responsive-image-grid/

You'll want something like

```
$(function(){
    $("#the_id_of_your_grid").gridrotator({
        rows:3,
        columns:10,
        w[some number]:{rows:3,columns:7},
        w[some other number]:{rows:3,columns:5}
    })
});
```

where the two "w[some number]:" are the equivalent of the CSS media query `@media (max-width: [some number]px)`. There's full documentation on the plugin's website